# Why vout->addresses in getrawtransaction is a table

Tags: address

I am reviewing Bitcoin transaction data as are returned by 'getrawtransaction' bitcoind command. I wonder why field: vout->addresses is a table and why it allows more than one address to be associated with the corresponding vout of the transaction? Are there any transactions in the blockchain with this field filled with more than one address? What is the use-case for that scenario?

Below example:

```
{
hex=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, txid=0c58341ad9b9846771c0be43bea903911d7e7bd3c5dea38ca4e684ba172821ab,
version=1,
locktime=0,
vin=[
    {txid=88774a982d273e64ed037ef621e88a965aa784ac0337197fc629e1f5c304bf98, vout=1, scriptSig={asm=3045022100df0fc6c8ebacf2986f98f4fd4fe790c870f43180fe4e21d21dae67bbc4b36d82022049889a9a992eb31f34f83fbfe721a2fee580d9a50c65274b477c63adef4c3b0701 04b1d702ecd1157a9ebd5194e39ee01d4bc317c1eec5aa49ca8457a08872cc34e0940404e5e17afcd970c324563f884c02c0bec6a4b840972cb17de6366da07917, hex=483045022100df0fc6c8ebacf2986f98f4fd4fe790c870f43180fe4e21d21dae67bbc4b36d82022049889a9a992eb31f34f83fbfe721a2fee580d9a50c65274b477c63adef4c3b07014104b1d702ecd1157a9ebd5194e39ee01d4bc317c1eec5aa49ca8457a08872cc34e0940404e5e17afcd970c324563f884c02c0bec6a4b840972cb17de6366da07917}, sequence=4294967295}, {txid=0b9e8ad1ecbf86b2a0e981618a060af21b57e23ae72b61511d8783a748cba84a, vout=1, scriptSig={asm=3045022100bc6d4f859b962510db20aa2b4f2018de8448101866637950f4852d57a5bfc3b402201b7da77067dea8b20ab069343f90b0e94191456d37dbb2bf84b31d3732c686e101 04bd33836b8247ddf109037ea57c0b23d23b215c6ab88926478f2fd884aa209b3296ec565ac54896a24675d0e584a0f8e56b98a2a1a64bd9ac9febaf942a90d047, hex=483045022100bc6d4f859b962510db20aa2b4f2018de8448101866637950f4852d57a5bfc3b402201b7da77067dea8b20ab069343f90b0e94191456d37dbb2bf84b31d3732c686e1014104bd33836b8247ddf109037ea57c0b23d23b215c6ab88926478f2fd884aa209b3296ec565ac54896a24675d0e584a0f8e56b98a2a1a64bd9ac9febaf942a90d047}, sequence=4294967295}, {txid=183d1fa81b027ec7656b7c4256463b4bfca35c36492c13d0d80b619d8aa25891, vout=1, scriptSig={asm=3045022100dc1f01e3a8850374c7929cd43c1b75bfb34093974ecc128d99895d279d541dca022023952ef2e3d8f97130a4490c114a432de5643c8cf413762860d9787c1c5364c401 0401de03d4723cef6a0f0fc278cffd257a611c17e177e80cc6f382d3c218aebf41263172a6d64f2f0210e620256b0bf3430c8251c60ef38083ff6c6a87e7d80698, hex=483045022100dc1f01e3a8850374c7929cd43c1b75bfb34093974ecc128d99895d279d541dca022023952ef2e3d8f97130a4490c114a432de5643c8cf413762860d9787c1c5364c401410401de03d4723cef6a0f0fc278cffd257a611c17e177e80cc6f382d3c218aebf41263172a6d64f2f0210e620256b0bf3430c8251c60ef38083ff6c6a87e7d80698}, sequence=4294967295}, {txid=2bb40d37362f62080ad0837e3275079d7278750d6fc391414d5fd544f2c0db7e, vout=0, scriptSig={asm=3045022069a96fdd4ec434aa8a70185cd861fe8bc3e82aa4db8967e6ed3d2f7ff0a1a3bd022100b1464600ae2a9d8b2c8e14217746ac3eba32e99068611847273e4886bca47cea01 047cfc6e801a25c1c52ba2e00859142e9ff03bea35670e9f94be22b8dbe4edae2a4046fa9c86d2d4c2af6402ae3a98d725ec1a30a461013a968294043ea33d3b79, hex=483045022069a96fdd4ec434aa8a70185cd861fe8bc3e82aa4db8967e6ed3d2f7ff0a1a3bd022100b1464600ae2a9d8b2c8e14217746ac3eba32e99068611847273e4886bca47cea0141047cfc6e801a25c1c52ba2e00859142e9ff03bea35670e9f94be22b8dbe4edae2a4046fa9c86d2d4c2af6402ae3a98d725ec1a30a461013a968294043ea33d3b79}, sequence=4294967295}
],
vout=[
    {value=0.09864623, n=0, scriptPubKey={asm=OP_DUP OP_HASH160 c962d40fc3302ad21a554d28509a4a9dcafc6243 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG, hex=76a914c962d40fc3302ad21a554d28509a4a9dcafc624388ac, reqSigs=1, type=pubkeyhash,

    // WHY MORE THAN ONE ADDRESS MIGHT BE PUT BELOW?
    addresses=[1KMqDGqpLBZPzfVGENErKce1hkaL8TnBwZ]
    } 

    },
    {value=0.28569421, n=1, scriptPubKey={asm=OP_DUP OP_HASH160 6999a9826e7f5b90e4f4a3ac5fb6cdfa32d39422 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG, hex=76a9146999a9826e7f5b90e4f4a3ac5fb6cdfa32d3942288ac, reqSigs=1, type=pubkeyhash,

    // HERE THE SAME: WHY MORE THAN ONE ADDRESS MIGHT BE PUT BELOW?
    addresses=[1AdN2my8NxvGcisPGYeQTAKdWJuUzNkQxG]}

    }
    ],
blockhash=0000000000000155303b637fda8f13f1778f58b64328c95ae201ccffbc5c6a8c, confirmations=1885, time=1368707765, blocktime=1368707765
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case a the scriptPubKey of a transaction is a standard M-of-N script, the N different addresses corresponding to the public keys are listed here.

There are likely very few or even no transactions that use this in the mainnet chain, as the few multisig transactions that occur are almost entirely using pay-to-scripthash, where the output doesn't contain the real script (only its hash), so it cannot be fully decoded.